# How to remove the light bulb in PHPStorm?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

Every time I try to select a line (for copying it, for example) a wild light bulb appears and blocks the mouse pointer. How can I remove this feature?

[image]

Comment: How many developers does it take to *remove* a lightbulb? Apparently six (and one more to joke about it).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, you CAN disable the bulb in v6. Settings (or Preferences on Mac)-> Intentions then uncheck the appropriate group. Poof. No more lightbulb getting in the way.

Comment: absolutely life changing!

Answer (score 12):

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show intention bulb`

[image]

**Please note** that hiding bulb and disabling intentions (as accepted answer suggests) are different things.

Yes, you may end up with hidden bulb in both cases but this way (in this answer) you can still invoke those useful intentions via keyboard shortcut (typically <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd>) while in other case they will be simply unavailable.

Comment: Isn't v6 the latest version? Where is v7?

Comment: v6 is the latest **stable** version. v7 just went into EAP mode recently (only 2nd public dev build .. still around 2-3 months before release). http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/